# Calling paint event inside a function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 
Platform : C#.Net

I am trying to call paint event inside a function in one of my forms in C#. The function is currently having two integer arguments, but I want the paint event of a panel to be called in that function, but I am getting error while calling the paint event. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the error ? We are not magicians !

Comment: The error is the name sender, e doesn't exist...

Comment: Give us screenshots and code samples.

Comment: private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 5, 5, px, py);
        }
        private void initilizeXY(int pxx, int pyy)
        {
            px = pxx;
            py = pyy;

            panel1_Paint(sender, e);

        }
 private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            initilizeXY(e.X, e.Y);

        }

Comment: Here in the above code, I want to call panel1_paint in the initializeXY(pxx,pyy) function...Could you please help now...

Comment: Ofcourse it will give you an error. There is no sender nor e while you call the method panel1_Paint(sender, e);

Comment: Please edit the question to include relevant formatted code.

Comment: When people ask for follow up information, it's usually an indication that you should **edit** your question. This is especially so if you're adding code since you can't format code (well) in the comments. Please **edit** your question, add the code, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button so that SO treats it as code.

Comment: Ok fine, next time will do that...

Comment: Why wait for the next time? Start now! Do it this time please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the coordinates to a field or list, what ever makes more sense for your case.

And then Invalidate the Panel, this will Raise the Paint Event, in which you will then be able to draw your line from the saved coordinates.

This is the only way to get what you most likely want without alot of trouble, because drawing to a window(Panel) in a non Standard way is not an easy Task to do.

[EDIT] Also:
Don't Forget you have to redraw the entire "Scene" on that Panel every time the Paint Event is raised, even if you use a Bitmap (backbuffer) as a backup, you need to blit this Bitmap onto the Panel again.

[EDIT] Sample:

```
    private readonly Stack<Point> _points = new Stack<Point>();
    private readonly Pen _blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black);

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var points = _points.ToArray();
        for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(_blackPen, points[i - 1], points[i]);
        }
    }
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _points.Push(e.Location);
        Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code to help me understand better... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Getting the Paint event handler to run just requires telling Winforms that the panel needs to be repainted:

```
    panel1.Invalidate();
```

You can also use Refresh(), that calls the Paint event immediately rather than letting Windows sort out the best time to generate the event.  Which is when nothing more pressing needs to be done, like responding to user input or dispatching messages that are sent instead of posted.  Not something you should ever consider, although it is a band-aid for not using a thread.

Answer (score -1):

None of the previous answers worked for me. After a while investigating, I have managed to raise paint event with the following instruction:

```
this.InvokePaint(this, new PaintEventArgs(this.CreateGraphics(), this.DisplayRectangle));
```

Comment: @Ibai - no it isn't. It is leaking a graphics handle for one thing.

Comment: "None of the previous answers worked for me" means that you are fouling up the message pump system in some way. This answer is just piling up one problem onto another.